# Best practice folder for systemd scripts

Tags: scripting, systemd

Where is the best practice suggested folder for scripts called by systemd?

If I have a Service MyService which executes myScript.sh, I know I have to put myService.service in /etc/systemd/system, but which folder should I put myScript.sh in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/myScript.sh`

`/usr/local/bin` is for any executable which is installed locally (i.e. not via your package manager).  Since your service is in `/etc` and not in `/usr/lib` or `/lib`, then we can tell that this service is locally deployed, so it pairs nicely with `/usr/local`.

`/usr/local/sbin/myScript.sh` can be more appropriate if the script should not be called by normal users.